# How to build two packages at the same time

Tags: ros, build, time, package, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ros jade and want to run ar_sys package. However, this is not available for jade version. So i get it from github. In case to work, the ar_sys needs the uvc_cam package. Every time i do make and build only the ar_sys package responds. What should I do to do make and build athe same time?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238999/how-to-build-two-packages-at-the-same-time/) by [dimitris anastasiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/27420/dimitris-anastasiou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-07-07**:
Is uvc_cam listed as a dependency in the ar_sys CMakeLists.txt file?

Unless it is explicitly listed as dependency, then CMake won't know to build it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try to

1- Download uvc_cam package from git in your catkin workspace

2- Download ar_sys package from git in your catkin workspace

3- Do `catkin_make --pkg uvc_cam` so it will compile the uvc_cam package first

4- Do `catkin_make` so it will compile all your catkin workspace while satisfying the dependencies

---

Originally posted by [jeanpolochon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27330/jeanpolochon/) with karma: 140 on 2016-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0